# Manage thread execution in a Threadpool class in C #

Tags: c#, multithreading

I created an application that uses dynamic threads, using the following function:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtConexiones.Rows)
        {
            Object ip = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["ip"].Value);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(setTimer), ip);
            Console.Read();
        }
```

You may notice that a number of threads are created, based on the number of records in the "ip" column, inside a Datagridview control, I mean, I have five records, so I have five threads.

In the same way `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (new WaitCallback (setTimer), ip);`
Creates the threads, and executes the setTimer function receiving as parameter the value ip, which is a String, to create a timer for each thread.

This process works perfectly, the threads are created, but when the program is executed, thread 1 is executed once, then thread 2 is left running indefinitely.

How can I manage the threads created by ThreadPool so they can be executed one by one, without running a thread x?

In the following image of the execution you can see how the thread 192.168.1.123 is executed twice and from there, the thread 192.168.1.124 is executed indefinitely, when what I would like is for both to execute at par. Greetings and thanks for your valuable help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpVMH.jpg)

Comment: Please don't insert images of text - just copy and paste the text, select it and type Ctrl-K to indent it in a preformatted section. I'm uncertain of the question here, though - If you want active control on threading, then you should consider using something other than the system ThreadPool, which is intended for simple task dispatching.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, I will edit this question with your observations. As for using another ThreadPool alternative, I would like to know this alternative, since I only want to manage the dynamic threads to execute one by one and that these execute without affecting the other threads that get to run at par. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

Since you wan't to run one thread at a time, I would just set a bool to identify whether or not the previous thread is still active before starting the next one.

I'd make sure to properly deal with sorting the threads because FIFO isn't guarenteed if you're dealing with multiple threads waiting on the same function (setting the thread priority doesn't solve this either).

Comment: In effect, my idea is to check if the thread is running and to exchange the execution between one and the other to consume the function setTimer ()